# Scroll page parallax when I click on menu bar?

Tags: html, css

my question is related to this question [parallax menu scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888413/scroll-page-parallax-when-i-click-on-navigation-menu-parallax-scrolling/35315125?noredirect=1#comment58338816_35315125)

I am trying to the same thing.

But, due to some issue, its not working. I think I am choosing the wrong id and class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SNAPCHAT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.stellar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scrip.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<a id="#nav1"></a>
<a id="#nav2"></a>
<a id="#nav3"></a>
<a id="#nav4"></a>

<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
   <div id="nav">
    <!-- <div id="logo"><img src=""></div>  -->   

        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://mediacentral.ie/" class="nav-icon" title="Home">Home</span></a></li>    
            <li><a href="#nav1">Sponsored Snapchat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#nav2">Snapchat Content</a></li>
            <li><a href="#nav3">Display Ads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#nav4">Media Central</a></li>
        </ul>


</div id="main">

    <div id="#nav1" class="image" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" >
<!--    <div id="content_1" class="content1">
 -->       


    </div>


    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="#nav2" class="image" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4"  ></div>
<!--     <div id="content_1" class="content2">
 -->        

    </div>

    <div id="#nav3" class="image" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4"  ></div>
<!--     <div id="content_1" class="content3">
 -->        



    </div>

    <div id="#nav4" class="image" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4"  ></div>
<!--     <div id="content_1" class="content4">
 -->        



    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// create the back to top button
$('body').prepend('<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>');

var amountScrolled = 300;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled ) {
        $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});

$('a.back-to-top, a.simple-back-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 700);
    return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my css

```
    body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: #fffc00;
}
.image {
    height: 750px;
    width: 100%;
    /*background: #55e6c5;*/
    }

.content {
    height: 750px;
    width:100%;
/*     background: white;*/    
    z-index: 2;
}
.content h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #464646;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 30px 60px;
}
.content p {
    font-size:20px;
    color: #343434;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 30px 60px;
}

#nav1 {
    background: url(../images/bg1.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
    height: 130%0%;
    padding:80px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}
#nav2 {
    background: url(../images/bg2.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
    height: 130%0%;
    padding:80px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}
#nav3 {
    background: url(../images/bg3.png) ;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
    height: 130%0%;
    padding:80px;
    text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
    z-index:0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#nav4 {
    background: url(../Images/bg4.png) ;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
    height: 130%0%;
    padding:80px 80px 0 80px ;
    text-align:center;  
   width: 100%;
    z-index:0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}
#nav {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%; 
    position: fixed;
    top:5px;
    left:0;
    background: #00000; 
    z-index: 100;

}

a[id= "#nav1"]:target ~ #main div.image {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
    transform: translateY( 0px );
}

a[id= "#nav2"]:target ~ #main div.image {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px );
    transform: translateY( -500px );
}

a[id= "#nav3"]:target ~ #main div.image {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px );
    transform: translateY( -500px );
}

a[id= "#nav4"]:target ~ #main div.image {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px );
    transform: translateY( -500px );
}


/*#nav #logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto 100px;
    text-align: left;
}*/

#nav #logo img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60)
}

li {
    float: left;
    padding-left:80px;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fffc00;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

a.back-to-top {
    display: none;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background: #333 url("../images/up-arrow.png") no-repeat center 43%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

/*#content_1 {position: relative;}*/
```

Please help me.

this is my code https://jsfiddle.net/vrg9qmp1/

Comment: What do you mean, "not working". You should explain what exactly your problem is.

Comment: when I click on the links in the menu, its does not slide down to that section.

Comment: this is project https://www.dropbox.com/s/nod1bqcvnoqm7fj/snapchat_parallax.zip?dl=0

please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `#` when defining an id attribute, only when referencing it in href or css selector. And only use the same `id` on a single element. So remove the `a` elements in the very beginning of your `body`, since you use the same ids later on.

This will **not** work.

```
<div id="#nav1"> 
<a href="nav1">
```

This **will** work:

```
<div id="nav1"> 
<a href="#nav1">
```

Comment: ok this atleast solved the issue to some extent. 

now, how do I put a parallax effect when clicked on options in menu

thanks again.

Comment: It's only possible to have parallax effect on a page with several layers of content. Your question makes no sense. Do you mean slow or smooth scrolling?

Comment: yes. I meant when I click on item in the menu bar, it should slowly or smoothly scroll to the corresponding part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063380/javascript-smooth-scroll-without-the-use-of-jquery